# Is there a possible suggestion on how to Transpose (columns <--> rows) in BigQuery where the input has more that 10,000 rows?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Currently I have a BigQuery table that has more that 10,000 rows.

For a Machine Learning Algorith that I already have, it ask for the data to had the days of data as columns. So a transpose command works as expected, but reach the BigQuery limit of 10K columns.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: 10K is a hard limit on BigQuery side. You cannot have more that that many columns

Comment: One option...I'm not sure if it would work, necessarily...is to build a JSON string for the result with more than 10,000 fields. I think the max row size is 100MB, though, so you might end up hitting that limit depending on just how many fields you have.

Comment: It's not possible to surpass [this limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) on columns. As mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11904846/3058302) by a Software Engineer at Google, it's a limit that they didn't expect to be surpassed. 

Is there any possibility to use your algorithm in 'batches'? Let's say, spliting the times you give it info in several times that doesn't surpass the limit?

Comment: can you share details of how you're running said algorithm? maybe something can be done in the interface btw BQ and it